# Trying to deploy an app in Production getting this No module named 'django.urls' error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

> Django Version: 1.8 Python Version: 3.5.2

Getting this Error when i'm running this app on production, from Windows to Linux PC

```
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'dasboard')


Traceback:
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/mydashboard/mydashboard/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from dasboard import views
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/mydashboard/dasboard/views.py" in <module>
  6. from rest_framework.response import Response
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in <module>
  13. from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in <module>
  30. from rest_framework.compat import postgres_fields, unicode_to_repr
File "/home/ubuntu/var/www/django_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py" in <module>
  26.     from django.urls import (  **# noqa**

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'django.urls'
```

[image: This is the Project Heirarchy]

I am not using Postgres simple sqlite db..

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your version of django rest framework, the current version (3.7) does not support django 1.8. You need rest_framework 3.6 to run on django 1.8

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be because your ROOT_URLCONF setting in your settings.py file is pointing to a non-existent file. Go to your settings.py file in your project and set it to something like this:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mydashboard.urls'
```